# How to filter data (queryset) in django admin interface by string length?

Tags: python, django

I would like to know, how to show only records where the 'code_key' length is 10 characters?

Currently if I use 'qs = Code.objects.filter(code_key.**len**()=10)' returns an error.

Thanks in advance.

**admin.py**

```
class CodeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['code_key','redemption_date','user','movie']

    #
    list_display = ('code_key','redemption_date','user','movie')

    #
    search_fields = ('code_key','user__email','movie__title')

    def queryset(self, request):
        """
        Filter the objects displayed in the change_list
        """
        qs = super(CodeAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs


    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        my_context = {
            'total': 'some value query',
        }
        return super(CodeAdmin, self).changelist_view(request,extra_context=my_context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Code(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code_key = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    redemption_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, blank=True, null=True)


    # ...
    def display_record(self):
        return (self.code_key.__len__() == 10)

    # ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.code_key
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using MySQL?

```
qs = Code.objects.extra(where=['CHAR_LENGTH(code_key) = 10'])
```

Comment: Just realize that this is Database specific. .extra() modifies the sql directly. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
filter(lambda code_object: len(code_object.code_key) == 10, list_of_code_objects)
```

It will remove all members of list_of_code_objects for which the statement len(code_object.code_key) == 10 does not return true.

EDIT: it does not affect the original list_of_code_objects; it returns a new list which contains only those objects in the original list which passed the test.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would like to know how or where is the filter code inserted?

I tried:
qs = Code.objects.all()
filter(lambda code_object: len(code_object.code_key) == 10, qs)
return qs

But the list displays all records with different lengths.

Comment: The filter function does not alter the original list; it returns a new list which contains only those elements which passed the test.  Assign the result from filter() to a new variable such as qs_filtered, or simply return the result of filter() directly.