# Django admin limit foreign key filters to entries within the table

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a couple models as below.

```
class Department(models.Model):
        id = models.CharField(max_length=100,primary_key=true)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class User(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dept= models.ForeignKey(Department,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)

class UserDisplay(VersionAdmin):
    list_display = ['id','dept'] 
    list_filter=['dept']
```

Say I have about 100 departments and only 3 Users. If I click on filter on the Django admin panel for the User model it shows all 100 departments. How can I limit the filters only to show the 3 departments used by this table ?

Comment: Please check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660915/how-to-filter-data-queryset-in-django-admin-interface-by-string-length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter` for this:

```
class UserDisplay(dmin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id','dept'] 
    list_filter=[('dept', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter)]
```

See details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter).

Comment: Thanks will try that out.

Comment: Works perfectly, Thank you.